# Wrong 2nd argument type, adapter cannot be converted to activity

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm using the openFbRefence method from a different activity in another java class but the 2nd argument has failed

I tried deleting the line of code but instead it destroys the app

```
public class DealAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DealAdapter.DealViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<TravelDeal> deals;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildlistener;
    public DealAdapter(){
        FirebaseUtil.openFbReference("traveluganda",this);//problem is here...on the 2nd argument.
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseUtil.mFirebaseDatabase;
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseUtil.mDatabaseReference;
        deals = FirebaseUtil.mDeals;
        mChildlistener = new ChildEventListener() {
```

This is the error I get....below
error: incompatible types: DealAdapter cannot be converted to Activity

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide minimal example which without **any** modifications from our side will let us reproduce problem you are describing. See more at [MCVE] and/or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: For now all we can tell is that compiler doesn't lie, so from "DealAdapter cannot be converted to Activity" we can tell that second argument of `FirebaseUtil.openFbReference("traveluganda",this);` should be of type `Activity` (or its subtype), but you are passing `this` which is instance of current class (`DealAdapter`) which is not subtype of `Activity`.